# Install glib under msys2

Tags: git, glib, msys2

I am working on installing the `msys2` environment to build `GIMP` under the `linux` `Windows` environment. I am following instructions at

https://wiki.gimp.org/wiki/Hacking:Building/Windows

Everything was going well until `./autogen.sh` for gegl. I get an error of missing glib. I have attempted in several ways to install it (using git to access source and build), but it really seems like I am going too deep into the system. Is there some way to install pre-built glib (a very basic tool) into msys?

Using

```
pacman -S glib
```

I do not find it.

Comment: And why do you install GIMP in that environment? When you use Windows?

Comment: I need to build GIMP, not use it.

Comment: And why you don't download the compiled sources?

Comment: Because. Do you know how to solve the glib problem?

Comment: I solved the problem. I had not read the install instructions carefully enough, and had installed the relevant libraries in the wrong place.

Comment: Try `pacman -S glib2`

Answer (score 1):

Search for the package with pacman like this:

```
pacman -Ss glib
```

On my system it outputs quite a few options. I'm not too sure which one you'd need in particular, but probably a bit more googling or perhaps the documentation on GIMP might help further.